# Matching disambiguating data to existing duplicate records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called transactions that has the ledger from a storefront. Let's say it looks like this, for simplicity:

```
trans_id | cust | date | num_items | cost
---------+------+------+-----------+------
   1     |  Joe | 4/18 |     6     | 14.83
   2     |  Sue | 4/19 |     3     |  8.30
   3     |  Ann | 4/19 |     1     |  2.28
   4     |  Joe | 4/19 |     4     | 17.32
   5     |  Sue | 4/19 |     3     |  8.30
   6     |  Lee | 4/19 |     2     |  9.55
   7     |  Ann | 4/20 |     1     |  2.28
```

For the credit card purchases, I subsequently get an electronic ledger that has the full timestamp. So I have a table called cctrans with date, time, cust, cost, and some other info. I want to add a column trans_id to the cctrans table, that references the transactions table.

The update statement for this is simple enough, except for one hitch: I have an 11 AM transaction from Sue on 4/19 for $8.30 and a 3 PM transaction from Sue on 4/19 for $8.30 that are the same in the transactions table except for the trans_id field. I don't really care which record of the cctrans table gets linked to trans_id 2 and which one gets linked to trans_id 5, but they can't both be assigned the same trans_id.

The question here is: How do I accomplish that (ideally in a way that also works when a customer makes the same purchase three or four times in a day)?

The best I have so far is to do:

```
UPDATE cctrans AS cc
SET trans_id = t.trans_id
WHERE cc.cust = t.cust AND cc.date = t.date AND cc.cost = t.cost
```

And then fix them one-by-one via manual inspection. But obviously that's not my preferred solution.

Thanks for any help you can provide.